# Multiple Java Project dependencies

Tags: java, netbeans, project, dependency-management

I have created 5 different Java SE projects in Netbeans 8.1 I want to create a single new project with an introduction window with buttons linking/opening the project linked to that button, and create a software from that.

I have added dependencies (jar files of other projects) in the main project->properties->library->compile->add project.

All the other projects are executing fine on their own when i run them in netbeans the window for operation is opening but when i called them from the main project nothing is happening. I have removed "main" class from all the other projects and called the set of instructions in the function of main project [Link to image of code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5aaNGQoIKlSbGNtTk1vcGR4QXc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any specific error message you are getting? Ideally you should use build tools like `maven` or `gradle` to manage dependencies between project. In your structure there should be one main project i.e it has `static void main` and the rest should be pure library meaning there should be no `main`.

Comment: Yes, you cannot have `main` in other project. You need to use `import` to use the class in your main project

Comment: I have removed main class from other project and added the set of commands in the main project->action listener->function of the button which envokes the other project. Still no output on button press.

Comment: Edit your question and add code to show how are you doing it

Comment: I have imported and no error is displayed. its just that i dnt have any output on button press